# How to display checked value for radio button collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, ruby-on-rails-5

Question about Rails 5 and `collection_radio_buttons`.

How do you have it display the checked value of a radio input when you try and edit the form?

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="radio">
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

With select box `f.collection_select` it remembers the value but not with `collection_radio_buttons`

My routes file is as follows

## Routes

resources :posts, as: :entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

It's because I'm using the `collection_radio_buttons` directly instead of using the form helper object.

From (not storing user value)

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="radio">
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To (now saving user values)

```
# Using the form helper `f.collection_radio_buttons` 
# instead of `collection_radio_buttons`. 
# Also removed passing the object in as an argument

<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="radio">
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`collection_radio_buttons` will automatically set the selected value. 
It finds the selected value from first two arguments. like in your example it will look for `@post.category_id` whatever value is returned from this method it will look for the corresponding radio button whose value is equal to this value and set that radio button as selected.

Please look at [API DOCK](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons#docs_body) for complete doc.

If it's not setting the correct value then make sure that `category_id` is set for the `post` your are editing

Comment: That is what I thought based on the documentation but in my situation I've changed the routes from resources :entries to resources :post, as: entries and wonder if this is my issue of the changed routes?

Comment: No this has nothing to do with the `routes`
It is expecting `@post` instance variable in your form.

Comment: I thought that but I created a new rails app and I have the same issue if I'm using the resources :posts, as: :entries but if I leave everything as :entries it works and change the controller from PostsController to EntriesController

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick.

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,{},{ checked: Category.first.id }) do |b| %>
  <div class="radio">
     <%= b.label do %>
       <%= b.radio_button + b.text %>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Dont you think this will always select the first category irrespective of our selection.